# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTemperature()

Tags: php

I am trying to use this but keep getting an error message:

> After editing the file on the web page the only thing showing up is "[".

Can anyone please advise me on how to resolve my issue.
I am a first year student I am not very experienced. This is my code:

```
    <?php
    include('forecast.io.php');
    $apiKeyParam = $_GET["apiKey"];
    $latParam = $_GET["lat"];
    $lonParam = $_GET["lon"];
    $unitsParam = $_GET["units"];
    $langParam = (isset($_GET["lang"]) ? $_GET["lang"] : null);
    $units = 'us';  // Can be set to 'us', 'si', 'ca', 'uk' or 'auto' (see forecast.io API); default is auto
    $lang = 'en'; // Can be set to 'en', 'de', 'pl', 'es', 'fr', 'it', 'tet' or 'x-pig-latin' (see forecast.io API); default is 'en'
    if($unitsParam != "") {
            $units = $unitsParam;
    }
    if($langParam != "") {
            $lang = $langParam;
    }
    //error_log(date(DATE_RFC822)." -- api=".$apiKeyParam.",lat=".$latParam.",lon=".$lonParam.",units=".$units.",lang=".$lang."\n", 3, '/home/weather.log');
    $forecast = new ForecastIO($apiKeyParam, $units, $lang);
    $condition = $forecast;
    echo "CURRENT_TEMP=".round($condition->getTemperature())."\n";
    echo "CURRENT_HUMIDITY=".($condition->getHumidity()*100)."\n";
    echo "CURRENT_ICON=".($condition->getIcon())."\n";
    echo "CURRENT_SUMMARY=".$condition->getSummary()."\n";
    $conditions_week = $forecast->getForecastWeek($latParam, $lonParam);
    echo "MAX_TEMP_TODAY=".round($conditions_week[0]->getMaxTemperature()) . "\n";
    echo "MIN_TEMP_TODAY=".round($conditions_week[0]->getMinTemperature()) . "\n";
    echo "ICON_TODAY=".$conditions_week[0]->getIcon()."\n";
    echo "SUMMARY_TODAY=".$conditions_week[0]->getSummary()."\n";
    echo "MAX_TEMP_TOMORROW=" . round($conditions_week[1]->getMaxTemperature()) . "\n";
    echo "ICON_TOMORROW=".$conditions_week[1]->getIcon()."\n";
    echo "MIN_TEMP_TOMORROW=".round($conditions_week[1]->getMinTemperature()) . "\n";
    echo "SUMMARY_TODAY=".$conditions_week[1]->getSummary()."\n";
    ?>
```

This is my forecast.io.php:

```
   <?php
   /**
   * Helper Class for forecast.io webservice
   */
   class ForecastIO
   {
   private $api_key;
   private $units;
   private $language;
   const API_ENDPOINT ='https://darksky.net/forecast/53.2789,-9.0109/uk12/en';
/**
 * Create a new instance
 *
 * @param String $api_key
 * @param String $units
 * @param String $language
 */
function __construct($api_key, $units = 'auto', $language = 'en')
{
    $this->api_key = $api_key;
    $this->units = $units;
    $this->language = $language;
}
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getUnits()
{
    return $this->units;
}
/**
 * @param string $units
 */
public function setUnits($units)
{
    $this->units = $units;
}
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getLanguage()
{
    return $this->language;
}
/**
 * @param string $language
 */
public function setLanguage($language)
{
    $this->language = $language;
}
private function requestData($latitude, $longitude, $timestamp = false, $exclusions = false)
{
    $validUnits = array('auto', 'us', 'si', 'ca', 'uk');
    if (in_array($this->units, $validUnits)) {
        $request_url = self::API_ENDPOINT .
            $this->api_key . '/' .
            $latitude . ',' . $longitude .
            ($timestamp ? ',' . $timestamp : '') .
            '?units=' . $this->units . '&lang=' . $this->language .
            ($exclusions ? '&exclude=' . $exclusions : '');
        /**
         * Use Buffer to cache API-requests if initialized
         * (if not, just get the latest data)
         *
         * More info: http://git.io/FoO2Qw
         */
        if (class_exists('Buffer')) {
            $cache = new Buffer();
            $content = $cache->data($request_url);
        } else {
            $content = file_get_contents($request_url);
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    if (!empty($content)) {
        return json_decode($content);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
/**
 * Will return the current conditions
 *
 * @param float $latitude
 * @param float $longitude
 * @return \ForecastIOConditions|boolean
 */
public function getCurrentConditions($latitude, $longitude)
{   
    $data = $this->requestData($latitude, $longitude);
}
/**
 * Will return historical conditions for day of given timestamp
 *
 * @param float $latitude
 * @param float $longitude
 * @param int $timestamp
 * @return \ForecastIOConditions|boolean
 */
public function getHistoricalConditions($latitude, $longitude, $timestamp)
{
    $exclusions = 'currently,minutely,hourly,alerts,flags';
    $data = $this->requestData($latitude, $longitude, $timestamp, $exclusions);
    if ($data !== false) {
        return new ForecastIOConditions($data->daily->data[0]);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
/**
 * Will return conditions on hourly basis for today
 *
 * @param type $latitude
 * @param type $longitude
 * @return \ForecastIOConditions|boolean
 */
public function getForecastToday($latitude, $longitude)
{
    $data = $this->requestData($latitude, $longitude);
    if ($data !== false) {
        $conditions = array();
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        foreach ($data->hourly->data as $raw_data) {
            if (date('Y-m-d', $raw_data->time) == $today) {
                $conditions[] = new ForecastIOConditions($raw_data);
            }
        }
        return $conditions;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
/**
 * Will return daily conditions for next seven days
 *
 * @param float $latitude
 * @param float $longitude
 * @return \ForecastIOConditions|boolean
 */
public function getForecastWeek($latitude, $longitude)
{
    $data = $this->requestData($latitude, $longitude);
    if ($data !== false) {
        $conditions = array();
        foreach ($data->daily->data as $raw_data) {
            $conditions[] = new ForecastIOConditions($raw_data);
        }
        return $conditions;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
 }
 /**
* Wrapper for get data by getters
  */
class ForecastIOConditions
{
 private $raw_data;
 function __construct($raw_data)
 {
     $this->raw_data = $raw_data;
 }
 /**
   * Will return the temperature
   *
  * @return String
 */
function getTemperature()
{
    return $this->raw_data->temperature;
}
/**
 * get the min temperature
 *
 * only available for week forecast
 *
 * @return type
 */
function getMinTemperature()
{
    return $this->raw_data->temperatureMin;
}
/**
 * get max temperature
 *
 * only available for week forecast
 *
 * @return type
 */
function getMaxTemperature()
{
    return $this->raw_data->temperatureMax;
}
/**
 * get apparent temperature (heat index/wind chill)
 *
 * only available for current conditions
 *
 * @return type
 */
function getApparentTemperature()
{
    return $this->raw_data->apparentTemperature;
}
/**
 * Get the summary of the conditions
 *
 * @return String
 */
function getSummary()
{
    return $this->raw_data->summary;
}
/**
 * Get the icon of the conditions
 *
 * @return String
 */
function getIcon()
{
    return $this->raw_data->icon;
}
/**
 * Get the time, when $format not set timestamp else formatted time
 *
 * @param String $format
 * @return String
 */
function getTime($format = null)
{
    if (!isset($format)) {
        return $this->raw_data->time;
    } else {
        return date($format, $this->raw_data->time);
    }
}
/**
 * Get the pressure
 *
 * @return String
 */
function getPressure()
{
    return $this->raw_data->pressure;
}
/**
 * Get the dew point
 *
 * Available in the current conditions
 *
 * @return String
 */
function getDewPoint()
{
    return $this->raw_data->dewPoint;
}
/**
 * get humidity
 *
 * @return String
 */
function getHumidity()
{
    return $this->raw_data->humidity;
}
/**
 * Get the wind speed
 *
 * @return String
 */
function getWindSpeed()
{
    return $this->raw_data->windSpeed;
}
/**
 * Get wind direction
 *
 * @return type
 */
function getWindBearing()
{
    return $this->raw_data->windBearing;
}
/**
 * get precipitation type
 *
 * @return type
 */
function getPrecipitationType()
{
    return $this->raw_data->precipType;
}
/**
 * get the probability 0..1 of precipitation type
 *
 * @return type
 */
function getPrecipitationProbability()
{
    return $this->raw_data->precipProbability;
}
/**
 * Get the cloud cover
 *
 * @return type
 */
function getCloudCover()
{
    return $this->raw_data->cloudCover;
}
/**
 * get sunrise time
 *
 * only available for week forecast
 *
 * @param String $format String to format date pph date
 *
 * @return type
 */
function getSunrise($format = null)
{
    if (!isset($format)) {
        return $this->raw_data->sunriseTime;
    } else {
        return date($format, $this->raw_data->sunriseTime);
    }
}
/**
 * get sunset time
 *
 * only available for week forecast
 *
 * @param String $format String to format date pph date
 *
 * @return type
 */
function getSunset($format = null)
{
    if (!isset($format)) {
        return $this->raw_data->sunsetTime;
    } else {
        return date($format, $this->raw_data->sunsetTime);
    }
  }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? It's line 19 causing the issue.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: `getCurrentConditions` method doesn't return anything, that's why `$condition` is null.

Comment: How do I get it to return

Answer (score 0):

In your code method `getCurrentConditions` is a void method and doesn't return anything. Update the method content to a something similar as `getHistoricalConditions` where you instantiate `ForecastIOConditions` class and return it.

Do note that your code may still fail unless the method is guaranteed to return a value and you should wrap it in an `if` statement.

```
$condition = $forecast->getCurrentConditions($latParam, $lonParam);

if ($condition) {
    echo "CURRENT_TEMP=".round($condition->getTemperature())."\n";
}
```

Comment: By doing that I don't get any error message but nothing shows up it is now just a blank screen.

Comment: As I said, make the method actually return an instance of the expected class and it will work just fine.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function ForecastIO::getHistoricalConditions(), 2 passed in /storage/ssd5/787/5300787/public_html/weather.php on line 18 and exactly 3 expected in /storage/ssd5/787/5300787/public_html/forecast.io.php:103 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd5/787/5300787/public_html/weather.php(18): ForecastIO->getHistoricalConditions('40.71', '-74') #1 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd5/787/5300787/public_html/forecast.io.php on line 103

Comment: I updated my question if you could now help me by telling me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Line (18):

```
$condition = $forecast->getCurrentConditions($latParam, $lonParam);
```

ought to return an instance of `class ForecastIOConditions` as promised in the comment block above the definition. At the moment, it doesn't so the call to the member function `getTemperature` causes the error.

EDIT in the light of edited question:

These lines:

```
$forecast = new ForecastIO($apiKeyParam, $units, $lang);
$condition = $forecast->getCurrentConditions($latParam, $lonParam);
echo "CURRENT_TEMP=".round($condition->getTemperature())."\n";
```

are still wrong. `$forecast` does now contain an instance of `ForecastIO`, which is what `$forecast->getCurrentConditions(...)` should be returning. So, in order to take your code a stage further, change the second line above to:

```
$condition = $forecast
```

Once you've got something working, you fix `getCurrentConditions(..)` to make it return the instance of `ForecastIO`.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: After doing this I edited my post with the new issue if you could please tell me what's stopping it from giving me my data.